# Change the fore color of gridview row base on row text

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rows

There is a row with "Correct" text in my database. However the if condition is never true.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblremark = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblremark");
            if (lblremark.Text == "Correct")
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cyan;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code and check what value are you receiving for that Label ?

Comment: Im receiving "Correct" and well as "Incorrect" for the lblremark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you are finding label correctly

```
if (lblremark.Text.Trim().ToLower().Equals("correct"))
```

Comment: Yes. It really works man. Thankx a million. I have been working on this for whole day. Finally u save my life.

Answer (score 0):

note: this was just off the top of my head

```
 //number of rows
        int rowNum = GridView1.Rows.Count;

        //go through each row
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++)
        {
            //get the cell text 
             string corr=  GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();

            //set color based on the text in the cell
             if (corr == "Correct")
             {
                 GridView1.SelectRow(i);
                 GridView1.SelectedRow.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                 GridView1.SelectedRow.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
             }
             else
             {
                 //do watever
             }
        }
```